# How can I import several URLs to wget?

Tags: wget, url

I use the following code to download "example1.com" with Windows. However, this code is limited to only one URL.

Is it possible to import a txt file which contains several URLs instead?

```
wget -erobots=off --no-parent --wait=3 --limit-rate=20K -r -p -U "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)" -A htm,html,css,js,json,gif,jpeg,jpg,bmp http://example1.com
```

Comment: You could write yourself a batch script which reads the txt file and invoced wget for each line. Don't really know about batch script because I'm more of a Linux guy ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I found the easiest way: `wget` has a command to import links from a text file.

```
wget -i mylist.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with *bash*, the Windows installer can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/) (when asked for components to install choose only MSYS), on Linux you probably have it as  default command line interpreter so you just run console emulator and you're ready to go. To run it on Windows open `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat`.

Let's say your URL database is called `db.txt` and it has each address in a separate line, with no spaces. Then the command to run `wget` for each address will be:

```
for line in `cat db.txt`; do wget -erobots=off --no-parent --wait=3 --limit-rate=20K -r -p -U "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)" -A htm,html,css,js,json,gif,jpeg,jpg,bmp $line; done
```

Notice that I've used accent characters (those to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> button), not aphostrophes. Before running this command you have to change your directory to the folder where the file is:

```
cd /home/YourUsername
```